# The Rest API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I signed up using: https://developer.salesforce.com/signup
I read that developer account by default have API Enabled. And looks like it is actually enabled.

Manage Users -> Profiles -> System Administrator

[image]

**Connected App Details:**

[image]

When I tried from Android Native app(using the mobile SDK and Forcedroid), it authenticates fine, but when trying to fetch the contacts it says:

```
The Rest API is not enabled for this Organization
```

What else needs to be enabled?

Comment: Can you try with a new developer org ? Looks like issue with developer org you spun and you can get SFDC support involved here .Thanks

Comment: @MohithShrivastava `Can you try with a new developer org `. You mean a new  account? Or can we have multiple organizations for a single user?

Comment: New developer account. You can spin as many developer org as you need

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes I could use the same `email` but a different `username` to create another account from here https://developer.salesforce.com/signup and it works. However does the Mobile SDK allow non-dev users to login? As in users who create accounts using https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp

Comment: Because if I signup using  https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp and use those credentials, it logs in but says `The Rest API is not enabled for this Organization` while trying to fetch contacts/accounts.